# Equal strings give -1 as a comparison result

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

i am comparing two strings,
one from database and other entered in comparison itself.
but when i try to compare identical strings, it gives false result.

currently my code is :

```
SqlConnection conchk = new SqlConnection();
conchk.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=eVoting;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
conchk.Open();
SqlCommand cmdchk = new SqlCommand("select voted from voter where FirstName ='" + N + "'", conchk);
SqlDataReader readerchk = cmdchk.ExecuteReader();
readerchk.Read();
String vchk = readerchk[0].ToString();
String chk = "N";
MessageBox.Show(vchk);
int cas = chk.CompareTo(vchk);
MessageBox.Show("comp res :" + cas);
if (cas == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("In if");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("In else");
}
```

Comment: Obviously the two strings aren't identical. Can you try comparing them character by character? Note that text is not as easy as it looks, there's things like unicode points, invisible conjoining space characters, combining characters, etc.

Comment: if the CompareTo returns != 0, then they differ. Watch their contents char-by-char or byte-by-byte, be careful about invisible whitespaces, hard spaces, breaklines and other nasty things like \0 character.

Comment: can you show me how..?

Comment: Are you comparing N with n or N with N?

Comment: as you can see in the code above, the String is actually a single charactor

Comment: First check length. Then compare char by char: var string a = "abc"; a[0] == strToCompare[0]; and etc.

Comment: Also dont use MessageBox.Show(vchk) to check your string literal from db, wrap it with some char like ' (MessageBox.Show("'" + vhck + "'")) to see if there are whitespaces etc etc, Though better way would be to use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine. Also consider using String.Equals() instead of String.Compare().

Comment: does the string created using toString() function and the one created directly are different ?

Comment: Cast chk[0] and vchk[0] to int and messagebox the values for each. Also messagebox the chk.Length and vchk.Length. Tell us what the values you see in the message box are.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen : the strin is actually 'N         ' which is returned from database....
thanks.. :)

Comment: what is the value of vchk you are getting?

Comment: In conclusion: store yes/no values as BITs

Comment: @kunal : it was `'N    '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `trim` the values before comparing:

**Replace this:**

```
int cas = chk.CompareTo(vchk);
```

**With following:**

```
int cas = chk.Trim().CompareTo(vchk.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to compare two strings

```
bool isEqual= string.Equals(vchk, chk);
```

`CompareTo` performs a case-sensitive comparison using ordinal sort rules.

```
         String vchk = "n";
         String chk = "N";

        int sac = chk.CompareTo(vchk);// result will be 1 .
        int cas = chk.ToUpper().CompareTo(vchk.ToUpper());  // result will be 0 .
        bool isEqual = string.Equals(vchk, chk);  // false
```

Please check your code or try to trim your string and use ToUpper().